# Multiple Spring integration test files with different context configs prevents successul persistence

Tags: spring, hibernate, persistence, integration-testing

I have two separate integration test files, each with their own context configuration files (XML).  When I incorporate both of them into the build cycle, I run into problems, but if I put the `@Ignore` annotation on one of them, everything works fine.

The specific problem I'm having is with persistence; when both integration tests are in the build cycle, one of my tests does not persist objects correctly to the database.  I don't get errors, and it says it's persisting, and Hibernate outputs the log entry saying it is inserting, but when I check the database table, nothing is there.  Then when I run the test by itself (`@Ignore` on the other test), it writes to the database table as it should.

Does it matter that I'm using some of the same variable names in the context config files?  For example, both files have a transaction manager called "deviceTxManager".  I figured this was OK since they are completely separate configuration files used for different tests.

Should I be somehow "purging" the context of the previous integration test before running the next test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was in my `persistence.xml` file.  I am using

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
```

which apparently is used separately by each separate integration test class.  So, the second integration test was recreating the database schema, thus purging the database changes made by the preceding integration test.

I thought `persistence.xml` was only accessed once before all integration tests are run, but apparently I was wrong; it is accessed separately by each separate integration test class and the database is cleared and recreated for each test class.